# throws 'noun' into, and throwing into 'noun'

Tags: sentence-construction, transitivity

I am wondering if there are alternatives to the classic throw 'noun' into,
something that does not require that middle noun?

Would this still work for ex :
She stops, violently throwing into a pond the motive of her anger.

Many thanks!

Comment: No, "throw" is a transitive verb and requires a direct object, whether there's a prepositional phrase with it or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can say "She threw the stone into the lake".  So the stone was the object that was thrown.

You can say "She threw into the lake a stone".  The reordering is odd and unnatural, but it still makes sense.  You might do this if the object phrase is particularly long and complex. But you might want to bring the modifier "into the lake" to the front.  "Into the lake she threw the photograph of her boyfriend that reminded her of the night she found out that he'd been cheating."

Your example is a "Colourless green ideas" sentence.  It is grammatical but meaningless. I don't know what it means to "throw a motive" A motive represents an abstract meaning; it can't be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a verb that means "throw something unspecified into"?

There are plenty of words that have that structure, but they are generally about sending particular kinds of thing in particular ways: *shoot* and *vomit* are two examples that come to mind. But I can't think of one that means more generally *throw*.